# R How to modify entries in a dataframe based on 2 conditions

Tags: r, data-cleaning

Using R to clean some messy data.
Let's say I have a data frame df:

```
    Ingredients      Bread  PB  Jam  
1   "Bread,PB,Jam"  
2   "PB,Jam"         x  
3   "Bread"          x  
4   "Bread"                     x  
...
```

How would I set up a conditional that would do something like:
Modify the entry in the Ingredients column if its corresponding (Bread, PB, Jam) column has an x, *and* with no redundant entries like "Bread,Bread"

So the cleaned Ingredients column would read:

```
Ingredients:
"Bread,PB,Jam" 
"Bread,PB,Jam"         
"Bread"               
"Bread,Jam"
```

Many thanks!

Comment: If you use `dput` function to post some data here, it would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I didn't know that was the protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can separate the comma-separated `Ingredients` into different rows, get all the column values in long format, `group_by` each `row` and `paste` the `unique` values in a sorted manner.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  #mutate_all(~na_if(., "")) %>% #Use this if you have blank values instead of NA
  separate_rows(Ingredients, sep = ",") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(value == 'x', name, value)) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  summarise(Ingredients = toString(sort(unique(value)))) %>%
  select(-row)

# A tibble: 4 x 1
#  Ingredients   
#  <chr>         
#1 Bread, PB, Jam
#2 Bread, PB, Jam
#3 Bread         
#4 Bread, Jam
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Ingredients = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Bread", 
"Bread,PB,Jam", "PB,Jam"), class = "factor"), Bread = structure(c(NA, 
1L, 1L, NA), .Label = "x", class = "factor"), PB = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA), Jam = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 1L), .Label = "x", class = 
"factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution according to your description

```
df$Ingredients <- apply(df,1, function(v) {
  if (sum(v[-1]=="x")>0) {
    u <- unique(c(names(v[-1])[which(v[-1]=="x")],unlist(strsplit(v[1],","))))
    paste0(na.omit(u[match(names(v[-1]),u)]),collapse = ",")
  } else {
    v[1]
  }
}
)
```

such that

```
> df
   Ingredients Bread PB Jam
1 Bread,PB,Jam     o  o   o
2 Bread,Jam,PB     x  o   o
3        Bread     x  o   o
4    Bread,Jam     o  o   x
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Ingredients = c("Bread,PB,Jam", "PB,Jam", "Bread", 
"Bread"), Bread = c("o", "x", "x", "o"), PB = c("o", "o", "o", 
"o"), Jam = c("o", "o", "o", "x")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Had never used the unique function before.